# language sub directory for wordpress via htaccess on multi domain server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a managed server with several domains on it. I control these via the respective host and forward them to the appropriate (wordpress) folder.
That looks like this:

```
# domain 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain1.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain1.com/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com
RewriteRule !^$ apps/wp_domain1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# domain 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
RewriteRule !^$ apps/wp_domain2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

But how do I proceed now if I have different languages as sub directory for a domain?
e.g. domain3.com/es/

I have tried a few things but not only are the styles missing (indicating a redirect error), the backend is unavailable and when I try to login I get a message that there is a redirect error.
I have entered the page accordingly with the language directory in the corresponding wordpress database. So this should actually work.

I suspect that I still have to do something in the htaccess within the wordpress installation, but not what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle different languages as subdirectories for a domain in your .htaccess file, you need to add specific rewrite rules for each language subdirectory.

Here's an example of how you can set it up for a domain with Spanish (es) and English (en) subdirectories:

```
# domain 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain3.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain3.com/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule !^$ apps/wp_domain3%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Spanish version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ apps/wp_domain3_es/%1 [L]

# English version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ apps/wp_domain3_en/%1 [L]
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT